# Transferable USB adapter for a broken flash drive

Tags: usb, connector, usb-device

A couple of hours ago the USB adapter on my flash drive broke. After seeing if I could fix it easily, decided I couldn't. I wondered whether there was a USB adapter that could easily and simply go over the PCB and connect with the USB adapter points on the PCB without soldering. There wasn't, atleast one that I could find.

My question is whether such a 'device' would actually work? If not, why?

If so, do you think its a good idea? If not, why?

Comment: Given any corrosion on the remaining bits of metal left on the PCB, and a small shock causing movement or shaking, the signal on the data pins could very well be disrupted causing data corruption or sudden disconnects; while this may work in very controlled circumstances to recover data once it is doubtful it would over longer periods.

Comment: I don't think that such solder-free adapter would exist.  Get a USB cable and snip-off its host side (with the type A plug) and solder the wires to the appropriate pads on the flash drive.  For an appropriately skilled and equipped person, the chances of success should be fairly good.

Comment: Why is this question being voted to close for repair ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that it the actual connector on the USB drive that has been damaged.

How you proceed depends on what you want to do.

If you just want to recover the data from the drive, the easiest method is to grab an old cord with a USB "A" connector on it (the connector that goes into your computer) and cut it short.  Then just strip and solder the wires from the cord to where the old connector used to be.

I do this on a regular basis for people - usually, the USB drive gets damaged when moving a laptop with the USB stick still inserted and the connector gets snapped off of the stick.  It's an easy fix but I don't consider it to be permanent.

If you want to actually restore the USB drive back to being a portable stick, you start off the same way but actually remove all of the plastic from the connector attached to the cord that you are using.  Then connect the wires from the connector to the PCB and test the drive.  If everything checks out fine, you mechanically attach the connector to the USB stick, using epoxy putty.

Regardless of which way you want to go, there is soldering involved.

Answer (score 1):

USB Flash Drives are cheap. Take advantage of that to maintain multiple copies of your data. Then when you break one of your flash drives you simply throw it away instead of trying to think up obtuse ways to circumvent actions that led to trashed hardware.